# SQL Management Studio can't drag table / object from Explorer to Query Editor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Ok guys, SQL Management Studio can't drag table / object from Explorer to Query Editor

I tried , and I don't know where to enable this future again :( Tried options menu... Aaaaa... Some one please save my day!

Comment: I had the same issue, could not drag a query into the editor. Found this solution: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1439333/Unable-to-DragDrop-Queries-from-Desktop-to-SQL-SERVER-Management-Studio-2005 which worked for me. Basically don't run SSMS as administrator. I have SSMS 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First... does drag drop still work on other programs that aren't SSMS?  I doubt that this is a feature you can turn on/off within SSMS.  It probably is something deeper in the OS.

If so - is the shift key or ctrl key on your keyboard stuck down?  I would also check options in the start menu.  Disabling drag/drop and right/click can be done at the system level or by group policy - but again it would affect more than just SSMS.

I've also heard of various viruses disabling drag/drop but again, it seems strange it would only affect SSMS.

Comment: Hic, you're right. I can't drag drop the icon on Windows too. Look like can't drag drop on everything.

Comment: @KhoaOfGOd: You might find [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/09fa7cba-a6a8-4fbf-b048-0bc62df7af61) useful then.

Comment: @KhoaOfGOd: Or [this](http://www.theeldergeek.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=28897).

Answer (score 11):

Fixed by hitting the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key a couple of times in my case.

Comment: This worked perfectly for also not being able to move tables in the Database Diagram editor.

Answer (score 3):

If you open SSMS in `'Run as Administrator'` mode then `Drag Drop file` won't work.

Close `SSMS` and open `SSMS` normally.
Drag-drop file feature will work.

Comment: Amazing that so many different things can cause drag and drop file to not work. I noticed my SSMS was acting funny after installing SSMS 18 and then uninstalling it and going back to using SSMS 17. I set up my shortcuts to run SSMS as Administrator. Running in normal mode has cleared this up for me.

Answer (score 2):

In SSMS 2012 (maybe other versions too), go to "Tools|Options|Text Editor|General" and click "Drag & Drop text editing".  That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was copying a large file in the background which seems to mess this up.  When the file was finished copying, drag and drop worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, I went to download ShellExview as a previous post displayed.
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html#DownloadLinks
I found that different versions of the Office libraries were loaded in memory, for me it happened as I am loading Visio 2010 and 2016 at different times.
**A reboot fixed the issue.**

(Exported the list before reboot when the issue was present and after reboot)
[image: Exported View of the ShellExportApplication]